# Why Google map Gocode return zero results on my android device (not on a browser)

Tags: java, android, google-maps, http, geocoding

I'm doing an appplication on Android, and I have to start Google Navigation (with longitude and latitude). All I've got is an adress (here an example : " * * * "). From that I have to get the coordinates.

So I use Google Geocoding, and did a HTTP request from Java :

```
public class LocationInfo extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject> {
    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... adresse) {
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(
                "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json"
                + "?address=" + adresse 
                + "&sensor=true");
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response;
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        try {
            response = client.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream stream = entity.getContent();
            int b;
            while ((b = stream.read()) != -1) {
                stringBuilder.append((char) b);
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        try {
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(stringBuilder.toString());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
        }
        return jsonObject;
    }
}
```

With this request I have the result ZERO_RESULT, but when I try it [on my browser](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=GAEC%20KER-HA-LAND%2029860%20-%20LE%20DRENNEC&sensor=true), I have a normal result.

It worked fine for a few hours on my devices, and after, i had this issue...
Anyone have an answer ?
Thanks !

Comment: Try using geocoder class its designed specifically for this

Comment: @Illegal Argument the problem is still the same, no responses... but thanks for the answer anyway !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`adresse` is not a string here but a vararg. You probably want to pick the first string in there so use `adresse[0]` here.

Comment: Thank you... I saw that it was not an ordinary string, but I didn't search further...

Comment: no problem :) if you're not familiar with varargs here is a nice example http://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/adk15notebook/varargs.html